# How to access objects from a different class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, class, oop

There are three classes :

A, B and C

The `__init__` of B creates an object of A. Using the mutators, I will be able to change the attributes of A from B for the instance created.

However, I am not unable to find any way to use that instance of A created by B to be used in C without passing the Object explicitly to the `__init__` method [ **not**  *C.__init(self, object: A)* ]

Is there any way to implicitly allow C to use that instance of A ?

I am new to python and not sure if this a valid question. I have looked at other sources where it explicitly passes the object to class C

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        x = []
        y = []

class C :
    def __init__(self):
        #[get obj1 without passing the instance in init]
        self.value = None

    def method1():
        self.value = len([]) #len(obj1 of A.x)


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        obj1 = A()
        obj1.x = [1,2,3,4]
        obj1.y = [1,2,3]

        obj2 = B()
        print(obj2.value) #this should be the length of x in the instance A created above
```

Comment: Any one of the Zen crusaders should post, that explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, i = ""):
        self.item = i

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A("hello")

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        b = B()
        print(b.a.item)

c = C()
```

Output:

```
hello
```

Comment: Thank you. That definitely helped.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have classes A and B:

```
class A:
    def hello_world(self):
        print("hello world")

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
    def hello_world(self):
        self.a.hello_world()
```

You create an instance of class B (which will create an instance of class A inside):

```
b = B()
```

You can then pass a reference to either `b` or `b.a` to any function of an instance of class C (either a constructor or not)

```
class C:
    def hello_world(self, a):
        a.hello_world()

c = C()
c.hello_world(b.a)
```

You can also use global variables:

```
class C:
    def hello_world(self):
        b.a.hello_world()

c = C()
c.hello_world()
```

Here the instances of class C will rely on variable `b` to be in place and just use its `a` attribute.

Using global variables in classes is generally considered to be hard to maintain and a bad practice. If your class depends on a value or an instance of some class you should pass the reference in the constructor (`__init__` function) or in the function that's using it.

Comment: Thank you. That helps it. I was not thinking in the correct direction.

Comment: So in the above case if we are writing a library, should we mention in the document what object names to be created. As in this approach, it is necessary to know the name of the object created in Class B [which is 'a'].

What if class A and B could not be edited and someone wants to implement them? Any object name other than 'a' in the new class [C here] will make it useless.

Comment: In general, I would take an instance of class A as a function parameter if I have to call a function on it or set something. In this case you don't have to specify the name in the documentation, because the caller passes the instance and you create the parameter name. (like in the first solution) If you rely on a global variable, then you have to specify that if there is no global variable called `b` or `a` present then that call will fail. This is also the reason why the later solution is not a good practice, it makes your code more fragile.

Comment: Great, I have a restriction on manipulating the number of arguments. Hence I think I have to take the second approach :)

Answer (score 0):

If these classes are in different different python files then you can also use these classes by importing the class name and creating an object of that class:
eg:

file1.py

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        x = []
        y = []
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import A
class C :
    def __init__(self):
    [get obj1 without passing the instance in init]
    self.value = None
    self.obj_a = A()

    def xyz(self):
      print "in class c"
```

file3.py

```
from file2 import C
from file1 import A
Class B:
    def __init__(self):
       self.obj_a = A()
       self.obj_c = C()

    def another_func(self):
       print self.obj_c.xyz()# it will print "in class c"
```